# iOS 9 network progress with Cordova and OnsenUI

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, onsen-ui

I would like to display network progress of my app using the native progress indicator on the status bar in iOS. I can't seem to find a plugin that will do this. Is this possible using Cordova with OnsenUI?